# Fonts.com @font-face implementation show status=cancelled in Chrome network tab

Tags: google-chrome, networking, https, font-face

I have a weird issue, today my fonts from fonts.com have a status cancelled in Chrome network tab.

The behaviour is that when I visit a secure page (https) and then navigate to a nonsecure one the fonts get cancelled. But the good news is that after a few refreshes the fonts get served properly.

Any ideas why this might occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the 'canceled' status is ususally 'masking' a 403 response which is related to the Fonts.com project's domain list which is used by our CDN to determine whether a page is allowed to use the web fonts.

If refreshing the page (eventually) fixes it, it's most likely that one or more needed domains have not been included in the project list. The 403 response is cached when a page on a such domain is loaded and requests the fonts and, if you're not explicitly clearing or disabling the cache, it is being used a few times on pages where the fonts would normally work before the browser re-validates the request.

We have a best practices FAQ for the project's domain list here:

[Fonts.com: Best Practices for Project Domain List](http://www.fonts.com/support/faq/web-fonts-domain-best-practices)

For further assistance, please send an email to webfontssupport@fonts.com referencing this question as well as a link to a page where you're having difficulty.

Answer (score 9):

Look at chrome console tab! there may be a CORS error - adding below lines to your htaccess file

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
```

should help